# What does this VSCODE symbol/icon mean? (Down Blue Arrow)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a text file that has this down blue arrow that snippets will not work for in Visual Studio Code Version: 1.83.1 (Universal)

[image: clip of file tab label]

I have tried renaming the file and copying the contents.  It seems to be something in the contents that trigger the symbol and behavior.

The contents are just random journal type of text.

Comment: Is that on the tab? It looks like a file icon. Have you tried renaming your file to, say, scratch.txt?

Comment: Can you please add a bigger screenshot? Is this the file tab? Might just be a file type indicator.

Comment: Go to the mention linked. I found the reason and solution.

Answer (score 0):

The file icon depends on its file type. The file type is determined by its termination. For files without termination and for the new files, not saved yet, VSCode tries to guess the file type based on its content.

[image: your image]
The file icon in your image denotes a [Markdown file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown).

VSCode provides [support for Markdown](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown) and is able to syntax highlight and preview (render) it. It does not need an additional extension for that.

The file probably contains near its top some lines that start with `#` (headers, in Markdown) or a bulleted list (consecutive lines starting with either `*` or `-`). These are the usual markers that make VSCode decides that the file contains Markdown.

Comment: fyi: this question is a duplicate.